# Project a 3D vertex to screen coordinates independently from OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

I have a vertex (x, y, z) and I want to calculate the screen location where this point would be rendered on my viewport. Something like [Ray Picking](http://schabby.de/picking-opengl-ray-tracing/), just more or less the other way around. I don't think I can use `gluProject` because at the time I need the projected point my matrices are restored to identities.

I would like to stay independent from OpenGL, so no extra render pass. This way I'm sure it would only be some math like the ray picking thing. I've implemented that one and it works well, so I want to project a vertex the same way.

Of course I have camera pos, up and lookAt vectors and fovy. Is there any source of information about this? Or does anyone know how to work this out?

Answer (score 2):

If your know your matrices (or at least know how to construct them), you can compute screen location for a vertex by multiplying its position with the matrices and then performing viewport transformation:

```
vProjected = modelViewPojectionMatrix * v;

if (
    // check that vertex shouldn't be clipped.
    -vProjected.w <= vProjected.x && vProjected.x <= vProjected.w &&
    -vProjected.w <= vProjected.y && vProjected.y <= vProjected.w &&
    -vProjected.w <= vProjected.z && vProjected.z <= vProjected.w
) {
    vProjected /= vProjected.w;

    vScreen.x = VIEWPORT_W * vProjected.x / 2 + VIEWPORT_CENTER_X;
    vScreen.y = VIEWPORT_H * vProjected.y / 2 + VIEWPORT_CENTER_Y;
}
```

Note that, as per OpenGL convention, `(0, 0)` is lower left corner, not upper left one.

Any math library with verctor and matrix operations can help you with that. For example, [`mathfu`](http://google.github.io/mathfu/index.html) or [`glm`](http://glm.g-truc.net).

UPD. How you can construct `modelViewProjectionMatrix` given camera position and orientation and projection params? We need two matrices (let's assume that model matrix is just an identity, i.e. vertex positions a given already in world coordinate system). First one would be the view matrix, which takes into account camera position and orientation. Here I'll be using `mathfu` since I'm more familiar with it, but almost every math library design with 3D graphics in mind has the same functions:

```
viewMatrix = mathfu::mat4::LookAt(
    cameraLookAtPosition,
    cameraPosition,
    cameraUpVector
);
```

The second one would be projection matrix:

```
projectionMatrix = mathfu::mat4::Perspective(fovy, aspect, zNear, zFar);
```

Now `modelViewProjectionMatrix` is just a product of those two:

```
modelViewProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix;
```

Note that matrix multiplication is not commutative, in other words `A * B != B * A`. So order in which matrices are multiplied is important.

Comment: Well your conditions at the beginning sadly are negative in my case.

Comment: If you know how to set the transformations in OpenGL, then you also know the matrices. Either you look them up in the docs ([gluLookAt](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluLookAt.xml), [glPerspective](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/gluPerspective.xml)) or you use the according methods each of the matrix libraries provides. Or you copy them back with `glGet(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, ...)` before resetting the matrix stack.

Comment: @Bitterblue I've amended the answer with a little bit of information about matrices used. Also, just getting them from glu or gl (as BDL suggested) is also an option.